# Последовательность удаления умных указателей

Tags: c++

В классе есть несколько `unique_ptr`, деструктор у как таковых отсутствует и необходимо задать правильную последовательность удаления данных обхектов, с вызовом для каждого своего метода `object_release_...`. В какой последовательности они будут удалены из класса при вызове деструктора класса?

```
class SomeSuperClass
{
    unique_ptr<super_t> m_some_super_ptr_;
    unique_ptr<super_child_t> m_some_super_child_ptr_;
};
```

Comment: В порядке, обратном созданию, т.е. в порядке обратном объявлению.

Comment: @Croessmah: Стандарт это гарантирует? Дело в том что объекты которые будут созданы создаются из [tag:c] кода.

Comment: да, объекты будут удалять сами умные указатели в своих деструкторах. А они точно будут удалятся в обратном порядке  (если только не сделать std::move куда то в другое место)

Comment: Почему бы просто не [попробовать](https://ideone.com/Fbcgpu)?

Comment: @free_ze, «просто попробовать» не гарантирует ничего, очевидно, что автор хочет гарантию стандарта.

Comment: @ixSci, следующим вопросом должно быть: "Почему так и всегда ли это так?" и тогда уже лезть в стандарт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не статические члены класса создаются в порядке объявления, а уничтожаются в порядке, обратном созданию, т.е. в порядке обратном объявлению.

> **12.6.2 Initializing bases and members**
>
> ...
>
> 11. In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
>     - First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>     - Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>     - **Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition** (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>     - Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
>
> [ Note: **The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization.** — end note ]

Comment: надоело писать по русски?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan это цитата из стандарта.

Comment: я пошутил, но если кроме шуток: вижу, что из стандарта, просто можно было перевести, можно было в начале отметить, что это цитата из стандарта. Это не критика